# Creating a Set Object from Dataframe (filtered with nonNaN values)

Tags: dataframe, set, nan, pyomo

Let's assume, I got a following dataframe, and I want to generate a Set-Object from that df.

```
>data
         x     
Name                              
A        NaN
B        65,2
C        NaN
```

I would like to create a set, which have only elements with nonNaN (float) values. So in above case it would be only "B".

If I create my Set-Object with following code:

```
# code
m.index = pyomo.Set(
    initialize=data.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
    doc='Index Set')
```

I get a set of "A", "B", "C".

What I would like to achieve is that: "B" should be the only element of this set, since it is the only element with a valid value.

**Expected Outcome:**

```
# output
(Pdb) m.index.pprint()
index : Index Set
    Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=1, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Mutable=True, Bounds=None
    ['B']
```

Answer (score 1):

After some digging and trying, I found the answer:

following code gives the expected outcome.

```
m.index = pyomo.Set(
    initialize=data[data.notnull()].index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
    doc='Index Set')
```